# Finder freezes when downloading files in Safari

Tags: macos, finder, safari

I am experiencing problems when I download archives from Safari to the Finder. What happens is that one archive keeps downloading and it never ends. Then when I try to enter to the Downloads folder in Finder it gets frozen.

In order to have it working, I need to restart my Mac.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Always the same download, or any file?

Comment: It happens with any file.

Comment: then 1) Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.

2) Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.

Comment: I've done that but still not working. It happens to me with two Mac computers.

Comment: Two different machines, any file. You're going to have to do some more research, because the chances of that commonality are almost zero.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to restart your Mac. You can simply use `Command-Option-Escape` and Relaunch the Finder app. I have this same problem, but it only happens when I have a Finder window open to the Downloads folder at the same time I download a file in Safari.
If the Downloads folder isn't open, the file downloads and all is well. This problem started with OS X El Capitan on a Mac with a clean install of the OS and a disk that checks out with no issues under the Disk Utility.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what's happening. Hope somebody else has the same issue as me. What would be the best way to let Apple know about this problem?